# Issue with RegQueryValueEx

Tags: c++

I am using RegQueryValueEx to read a String value (REG_SZ) from  the registry.
The value if this registry contains some Japanese Characters along with english.
For eg:  C:\Program Files\MyReg\ﾁﾁﾁ\helloworld

I am using the following code snippet:

```
BYTE* dwValue = 0;
DWORD  dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwType = SZ_REG;
TCHAR* valueName= TEXT("test");
//Get the size 
if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valueName,NULL,&dwType,NULL,&dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{   
dwValue = new BYTE[dwSize];

if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valueName,NULL,&dwType,( BYTE* )( dwValue ),&dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) )
   _tprintf(TEXT("The value is  %s"),(TCHAR*)dwValue);
}
```

The output i get is-

The value is C:\Program Files\MyReg\

This exe is console application and has got  UNICODE preprocessor defined.
If i remove it then it works correctly and gives the correct string.
I am not sure whats going wrong due to UNICODE.

-Thanks

Comment: Try RegQueryValueExA instead of RegQueryValueEx

Comment: This cannot be your actual code since it contains many typos (`value`, `dValue` etc.). Please post some actual, complete code.

Comment: Also, do you also have `_UNICODE` defined? Functions like `_tprintf` depend on `_UNICODE`, not `UNICODE`. Better use the 16-bit versions (`RegQueryValueExW`, `wprintf`) directly.

Comment: Thanks rkosegi ,Philipp.
Using RegQueryValueExA , works and gives the correct Value.  But not sure why I should have to do that ?    Both  _UNICODE and UNICODE are defined .  When I tried to use RegQueryValueExW  I still get the  incomplete registry value back (which is missing the double byte characters).

Comment: This surely has more to do with the fact that the console isn't very good at displaying Japanese characters unless your machine has a Japanese code page selected as the default system code page.  Use the debugger or MessageBox() instead.

Comment: Thanks , yes I was just expecting to see  some ??? in the console. I did actually test it on a Japanese OS as well where had the same results.

Comment: There's a lot of very strange casting here. I'd look to get rid of that.

Comment: Hi David , which casting should be get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed my problem but it still confuses me though.

My project was based on VS IDE 2003 , If i compiled the same code in VS 2003 with UNICODE/_UNICODE   , it will fail to give me the complete string  meaning  (it will remove the characters starting from the first Double Byte character).
If I build with VS IDE 2003  WITHOUT the  _UNICODE/UNICODE flag , it WORKS CORRECTLY and gives me the complete string  and then depending on my code page I may get to see the actual characters or bunch of question marks (???) for each double byte character.

If I compile the same code with VS 2005 , then I get the correct and complete string (from the registry)  irrespective of whether or not I have defined _UNICODE/UNICODE.
But when the characters can't be displayed on Japanese OS console as well as english OS console. But MessageBox() displays them correctly.
In order to display the characters correctly on Japanese OS console  I am forced to compile without the _UNICODE/UNICODE flags. (which i m not able to understand ..)
In my code there  is no change at all what i have to make except compiling it with VS 2005 to get the problem fixed(except the display problem)